# how to add validation required_if many filed is empty not work?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

how to add validation required to another filed if two filed is empty ?

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XBGG.png)

I want edit it because this code if one input has value not complete but show me message required

second validation in image work good but l want write it better as first code

example:

```php
 $this -> validate($request, [
     'test' => 'required_without:is_for_women,is_for_family,is_suitable_for_children,is_for_men',
 ]);
```

but this code is wrong because show me message required if any filed empty.

thanks.

Comment: Don't post images of code. All code need to be copy/pasted into the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done solve it.

code in PlaceController

```
   $this->validate($request, [
        'category' => 'required_without_all:is_for_women,is_for_family,is_suitable_for_children,is_for_men',
   ]);
```

To read about validation in docs [required_without_all](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-required-without-all).

Thanks, guys.